# iPhone charging gives warning: "[cannot connect USB device]" then "[enter passcode]"

Tags: iphone, usb, charging, lightning

I am using iPhone 6 running iOS 12.4.

I had been having trouble getting good connection between lightning cable and charging port. I cleaned-out lint/dirt from the port about 1 month ago, and all was ok.

Then, starting 7 days ago, 5 times since then when I insert lightning cable to re-charge I get an error that reads something like: **Cannot connect USB device. Enter passcode.** But, there is no clear presentation of how to enter the passcode (which doesn't matter because I would not do it anyway).

Each time, I pull-out the cable. Blow into the re-charge port. Choose a different lightning cable and re-insert. On either the 1st or 2nd re-insert, and wiggling it around a little, with the new cable, the **Cannot connect USB device** message goes away and charging happens ok. I've never heard of "*connecting USB devices to iPhones*", so is this a clue?

That is such a strange error message about "*cannot connect a usb device to the phone*", but is this a standard progression of a complete hardware failure of my charging port?

Comment: It sounds a bit like this, if not identical - http://osxdaily.com/2018/11/21/unlock-iphone-to-use-usb-accessories-message/ - can you confirm?